# Change the selectbox value according to the database value

Tags: php, mysql, dom

I have a select box which have more than 750 option value.Actually it is hardcoded in the HTML page.I need it to insert a separate table and using foreach to populate it.Please let me know is it possible?

```
<select name="PassNum"> 
<option value="12HTQD" <?php if($PassDetail['Mak']=="12HTQD"){?> selected="selected"<?php } ?> >12HTQD</option>
<option value="12HTMD" <?php if($PassDetail['Mak']=="12HTMD"){?>  selected="selected"<?php } ?> >12HTMD</option>
<option value="78HTMD" <?php if($PassDetail['Mak']=="78HTMD"){?>  selected="selected"<?php } ?> >78HTMD</option>

---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
 </select>
```

It is too much time consuming if i do it manually.

**UPDATE**

I want the hardcoded values from the given HTML to DB..So i can populate it from DB..Now its hardcoded..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you want to get the database value and then set it to select box or you want to save database value to database.

Comment: I want the Hardcoded values from the given HTML to DB..So i can populate it from DB..Now its hardcoded..

Comment: Please change the title of the post accordingly if you can

Comment: Okay, Try my answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks Nirmal Ram..I got the solution from another guy.Actually that was i am asking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this way..

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches["1"];
}


$str = '<option value="12HTQD" <?php if($PassDetail['Mak']=="12HTQD"){?> selected="selected"<?php     } ?> >12HTQD</option>
<option value="12HTMD" <?php if($PassDetail['Mak']=="12HTMD"){?>  selected="selected"<?php } ?> >12HTMD</option>
<option value="78HTMD" <?php if($PassDetail['Mak']=="78HTMD"){?>  selected="selected"<?php } ?> >78HTMD</option>
';


$txt = getTextBetweenTags($str, "option");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($txt);
```

now it will return an array..You can use your logic to inert the array values to db..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this using jquery just do this

```
$("select[name=PassNum] option").filter(function() {
    //may want to use $.trim in here
    return $(this).val() == "<?php echo $PassDetail['Mak']; ?>"; 
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="PassNum"> 
<option value="12HTQD" <?php if($PassDetail['Mak']=="12HTQD"){?> selected="selected"<?php     } ?> >12HTQD</option>
<option value="12HTMD" <?php if($PassDetail['Mak']=="12HTMD"){?>  selected="selected"<?php } ?> >12HTMD</option>
<option value="78HTMD" <?php if($PassDetail['Mak']=="78HTMD"){?>  selected="selected"<?php } ?> >78HTMD</option>

---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
</select>
```

try to change this one to this.

```
<select name="PassNum">
<?php foreach($data as $d){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $d['variable_name'];?>" <?php if($PassDetail['Mak']==$d['variable_name']){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> ><?php echo $d['variable_name']; ?> </option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table passNumValues with id,passNumValue attributes.
2. And insert values to this table.
3. code like this.

   ```
   $query_disp="SELECT * FROM passNumValues";
   $result_disp = mysql_query($query_disp, $conn);
   while($query_data = mysql_fetch_array($result_disp))
   {
   ?>
   <option value="<?PHP echo $query_data['passNumValue'];?>" <?php if($PassDetail['Mak']==$query_data['passNumValue']){?> selected="selected"<?php } ?> ><?PHP echo $query_data['passNumValue'];?></option>
   <?PHP
   }?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="PassNum">
    <? foreach($arr as $v){?>
        <option value="<?=$v['value'];?>" <?=($v['Mak']==$d['name'])?'selected="selected"':"" ?> ><?=$v['name']; ?></option>
    <? } ?>
</select>
```